# Lipo error when coverting iOS project to ARC

Tags: xcode, architecture, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.6, lipo

I'm trying to convert my iOs project to use ARC but am receiving a lipo error below is the command and error

Command:

```
CreateUniversalBinary /Users/samichaudry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CartoonQuiz-bqmbxfcdkldmbqawgrfmjtebypuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CartoonQuiz.app/CartoonQuiz normal "armv7 armv7s"
cd "/Users/samichaudry/Projetcs/CartoonQuiz/Application/V1.01 New Design Universal/Application"
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
lipo -create /Users/samichaudry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CartoonQuiz-bqmbxfcdkldmbqawgrfmjtebypuk/Build/Intermediates/CartoonQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/CartoonQuiz.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CartoonQuiz /Users/samichaudry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CartoonQuiz-bqmbxfcdkldmbqawgrfmjtebypuk/Build/Intermediates/CartoonQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/CartoonQuiz.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/CartoonQuiz -output /Users/samichaudry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CartoonQuiz-bqmbxfcdkldmbqawgrfmjtebypuk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CartoonQuiz.app/CartoonQuiz
```

Error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /Users/samichaudry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CartoonQuiz-bqmbxfcdkldmbqawgrfmjtebypuk/Build/Intermediates/CartoonQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/CartoonQuiz.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CartoonQuizCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Does the file referenced by lipo exist or is it of size zero?

Try changing your build target to a simulator build, clean and re-run.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly, I had the target set to iOS device but had no device connect, changing the target to simulator fixed it.

Comment: Simply changing to simulator build fixed it for me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Still useful over a year later, we just took over for development of this app, they started development in February and they weren't using ARC...

Answer (score 0):

Removing architecture `armv7` while leaving `armv7s` (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15279589/1255674)) did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add i386 to my valid architectures to get this to work.